Problem with Youtube image api and nodejs https request
Im trying fetch youtube videos thumbnails using following endpoint :
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/<Video-ID>/sddefault.jpg
With my nodejs code:
const https = require('https');
https
      .get(
        'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/<Video-ID>/sddefault.jpg',
        {
          agent: new https.Agent({ keepAlive: true, keepAliveMsecs: 15000 }),
        },
        (response) => {
           response.pipe(stream);
           stream.on('finish', () => {
             stream.close();
           });
        }
      )
      .on('error', (err) => {
        console.error('Error downloading file:', err);
      });

But im getting this error :
connect ETIMEDOUT 10.10.34.35:443
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) {
  errno: -4039,
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '10.10.34.35',
  port: 443
}

I am more surprised that the image is loaded in the browser or apps like postman but not with my code.
Maybe its would be helpful to say that im using proxy with my network as error indicates to 10.* ip address which is private one.

Yes, the problem is happening because Node is not going through your proxy server and your request is timing out.
So you can:
1 - Run you code via your proxy
You can use a famous proxy handler on node called https-proxy-agent, you can install it by running:
npm install https-proxy-agent

After that you need to add your proxy setup on it:
const https = require("https");
const HttpsProxyAgent = require("https-proxy-agent");

// Define your proxy server address, you can add it as a .env too
const proxy = "http://your-proxy-server.com:8080"; 

// Initialize the https-proxy-agent with the address to the proxy server
const httpsAgent = new HttpsProxyAgent(proxy);

https
      .get(
        'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/<Video-ID>/sddefault.jpg',
        {
          agent: httpsAgent, // Use the proxy agent
          keepAlive: true, 
          keepAliveMsecs: 15000
        },
        (response) => {
           response.pipe(stream);
           stream.on('finish', () => {
             stream.close();
           });
        }
      )
      .on('error', (err) => {
        console.error('Error downloading file:', err);
      });

2 - Disconnect from your proxy

hi. thank you and you were right, it was about my proxy connection. but i didn't mean a remote server proxy, i was talking about a local proxy-vpn app like psiphon.  then i tried to connect to my proxy with "proxy-agent" npm module which solved my problem. your second option is not possible for our situation but thanks for guide

Happy to see your code worked in the end! :D
